# Vue.js - Component Height and Width not computed

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I have the following code within my component:

```
computed: {
    gridWidth()  { return (this.$el && this.$el.offsetWidth)  },
    gridHeight() { return (this.$el && this.$el.offsetHeight) },
},
mounted(){
    console.log(this.$el && this.$el.offsetWidth, this.gridWidth, this.$el && this.$el.offsetHeight, this.gridHeight)
},
```

The console output is:

```
1766 undefined 931 undefined
```

Why are the computed properties undefined?

Would be a watcher the right way? Why and how to realize?

Comment: Did you try this in your mounted.......this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$el && this.$el.offsetWidth, this.$el && this.$el.offsetHeight, this.gridHeight)})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically related to how [reactivity in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) works. By default your DOM is not continually providing updated values.

You can either play around with [vm.$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) and [vm.$watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) to basically attach a watcher after the rendering has been finished, or you can use a small library which does exactly what you are looking for:

[vue-resize-directive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-resize-directive)

Comment: Thanks. Now, I realized it with the resize event.